# Remove spaces between commas using command line

Tags: linux

If I have a file like

```
1050505,Some Customer,  1  ,  1  ,Some Order, 5  ,  6  Item
1050505,Some Customer,  1  ,  1  ,Some Order, 5  ,  6  Item
1050505,Some Customer,  1  ,  1  ,Some Order, 5  ,  6  Item
1050505,Some Customer,  1  ,  1  ,Some Order, 5  ,  6  Item
1050505,Some Customer,  1  ,  1  ,Some Order, 5  ,  6  Item
```

But I need to strip spaces except for when they are between words (i.e. strip spaces after or before a comma).

```
1050505,Some Customer,1,1,Some Order,5,6  Item
```

What would be the simplest method of doing this by standard command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of tools.  Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\s*,\s*/,/g;' file.txt
```

sed:

```
sed 's/,\s\+/,/g; s/\s\+,/,/g' < file.txt
```

awk:

```
awk '{gsub(", +", ",", $0); gsub(" +,", ",", $0); print $0}' file.txt
```

Comment: Note `awk ... file` is the same as `awk ... < file`. There is no need to indirection.

Comment: The `sed` command can be shortened to `sed 's/, \+\| \+,/,/g'`

Comment: The file bit is true of `sed` too, but what does it matter? :-p

Comment: However if you add the `-i` flag and don't redirect the file it will edit it in place (the changes will stick).

Comment: I say it doesn't matter because you can redirect to an output file either way

Comment: @KyleBurton Thanks! If I wanted to pipe this `sed` version, I've tried `echo "$(pull_data $a $b)" | sed 's/, \+\| \+,/,/g' > $id.csv` but that doesn't seem to remove the spaces, is this correct?

Comment: @user2656114 if pull_data prints to stdout, then you might be able to just pipe it through sed: `pull_data $a $b | sed 's/, \+\| \+,/g'` test it first without redirecting to the file $id.csv until you get the output you expect, then finally redirect it.  Can you share what pull_data's output looks like?  That would help.

Comment: @KyleBurton Yes it works ok using `pull_data $a $b | sed 's/, \+\| \+,/g'` but breaks when I add the `> file`.

Comment: @user2656114 you're right, I made the edit based on @Conner's suggestion, but didn't test it.  If it worked with `cat file.txt | sed ...`, then adding redirection `> file` works for me.  I'm not sure what is different for you.

Comment: @KyleBurton Ok doing `pull_data $a $b > $id.csv` and then `sed 's/,\s\+/,/g; s/\s\+,/,/g' < $id.csv` shows the correct data. How do I combine that in to the `pull_data $a $b ...`. Last time I tried it broke everything!

Comment: @user2656114 you _should_ just be able to pipe `pull_data $a $b ...` into `sed '...'`, afaik that's how pipes work.  If `pull_data` is writing to stdout, `sed` is reading from stdin, then `pull_data ... | sed '...'` should be equivalent.  Can you do `pull_data ... | cat` and `cat | sed '...'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/[\s]+,/,/g;s/,[\s]+/,/g' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sed` command would do it:

```
sed -i 's/,[ ]*/,/g' /path/to/file
```